# How to unwrap optionals in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2, conditional-statements, option-type

I'm having trouble unwrapping this safely. Anyone have any suggestions? I have tried using a if let statement but can't get it to work.

```
     meltingPoint.text = elementArray[indexPath.row].meltPoint
```

I would like to change my label text "meltingPoint.text" to "N/A"

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use "??" as in:

```
     meltingPoint.text = elementArray[indexPath.row].meltPoint ?? "N/A"
```